# How to continually repeat animations?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I know in my commands I can set the repeatCount and repeatMode. The count takes in a value and repeats up to that amount. But what if I want it to continually loop over and over again until the next intent?

```
"repeatCount": 30,
"repeatMode": "reverse",
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is currently not possible. You can, however, set the repeatCount to a large number.